# How many moons do I need to throw at a planet to shatter the tectonic plates?

Tags: geography

Original question - {So basically, I have this planet of *many* islands, with a large set of rings across it, and the only planetary backstory I could think of is throwing some moons at it, which leads to it having a very messy set of tectonic plates.

So how many moons do I need to use to shatter it.}

updates - 1. I forgot to explain the island geography to the full extent, they aren't just islands, they're series upon series of *mountainous*, volcanic islands, stuff that would be caused by many divergences and convergences.

2. The deorbiting of a vessel such a size also is an important factor in creating a set of planetary rings.

Comment: What does many islands have to do with the plates(plate count, island count are independent)? Why would fracturing a plate cause the majority to no longer move as one? Are these impacts changing the mantel flow ? I suspect you are asking the wrong question, why do you want to shatter the plates?

Comment: I agree with Gault, there seems to be something you have in mind that you're not telling us - to make it clearer where you're trying to get to with the question, can you tell us what your objectives are? (We'd not be able to answer the Q as written, as  you've not specified the size/mass or velocity of impact). For an [example question on impacts](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2796/asteroid-impact-how-big-does-it-have-to-be-to-globally-affect-plate-tectonics) take a look at that one. (Hold in mind the rules are tighter now than when that was written, 1 Q per post)

Comment: How big the moons? how big the planet? how large the plates? what makes you think they won't just reform over time anyway? .. all they are is cooled magma after all (think of ice on a pond, throw stones at it to smash the ice, overnight the ice reforms) .. no expert on this but I imagine other than in the very short term (in geological time that is) size, shape and number of plates is dictated by the convection currents in the core and magma and tossing big stones (aka moon's) at them isn't going to have any durable effect .. interested to hear from any who is an expert on this though 

Comment: @Pelinore: Throwing *one* Moon-sized object at a planet like Earth may not *shatter* the tectnic plates, but it will likely *melt* them.

Comment: @AlexP Yep, would seriously readjust the surface, but I'm guessing they'd harden back into roughly the same number of plates floating on top of the magma was what I was getting at.